I have a ListView.builder in the drawer. I want to preserve its state when the drawer close and opens again.tried AutomaticClienkeepAlive doesnt work
I'm developing a Flutter application where I have a widget (BatteryList) inside a drawer that fetches and displays data using Blocs. I'm using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to preserve the state of this widget when the drawer is opened and closed. However, I'm encountering issues where the state seems to reset when I close and reopen the drawer. Here's a simplified version of my code:
I'm using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to preserve the state of this widget when the drawer is opened and closed. However, I'm encountering issues where the state seems to reset when I close and reopen the drawer.

"Here's a simplified version of my code". It seems you forgot something

This happens because the app rebuilds every time the drawer is opened.
The easy way to solve this is to use give the listview a unique key of PageStorageKey. It will preserve the state of the listview. It can also be used with tabs.
Sample usage below.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return  Scaffold(
    drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView.builder(
        key: const PageStorageKey<String>("unique_string"),
      itemCount: 150,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, int) => Center(
        child: Text(int.toString()
        ),
      )
      )
      ),  
    appBar: AppBar(
      title:const Text("Test"),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: const Center(child: Text("Drawer test"),)
    );

}
